# Root path for CSS and images

Tags: css, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to configure CakePHP 1.3 on WAMPserver.

The problem is that my CSS is not found at `localhost://dreamdeal/css/generic.css`.

How can I set the root path in my `webroot/index.php`?

I set this path as

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'wamp' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'dreamdeal' );
}
```

but that did not fix the error.

Comment: For starters, `localhost` is the [host](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Which_part_is_the_host_of_URL_address), not the [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the [documentation for the folder structure](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure) from CakePHP. If you want to use CSS, the folder for that needs to be in the Cake `webroot/` folder. It should not be on your `localhost` root path.

Comment: my css is cakephp default css and it stay in webroot folder. but my webroot url is not correct thats why css and images are not found.  please tel me how can i configure my webroot path?